# Does alcohol really helps to get substances get faster into the bloodstream?

Tags: hematology, muscles, nutrition, blood-circulation, alcohol

I saw [the video](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=schwarzenegger%20shnapps&t=brave&iax=videos&ia=videos&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4AqIzkThbqE) where Arnold Schwarzenegger cooks some protein cocktail and adds Austrian Schnapps to the mix, saying that it's to make everything get faster to the blood. Is it true or some kind of a joke?

One person said this:
`Alcohol inhibits protein synthesis, which is necessary for muscle building. It affects Glucose, which is needed for energy and recovery, so in this aspect it'll stunt your recovery and energy. For workouts, it dilates your blood vessels forcing blood into limbs and leaving core colder, what this means is that you'll loose performance. The article mentions that this mainly affects endurance`
He says about effect of alcohol, that's a good question too.
And what about actually getting stuff faster into the bloodstream?

Comment: The total conclusion of all studies of alcohol is that moderate alcohol consumption has no beneficial effects on health. Some studies said a bit of alcohol is good for you... Most alcohol is metabolised by an enzyme in your liver cells known as alcohol dehydrogenase (ADH). ADH breaks down alcohol into acetaldehyde, and then another enzyme, aldehyde dehydrogenase (ALDH), rapidly breaks down acetaldehyde into acetate. Some people drink the wrong alcohol for covid... which ADH enzyme instead turns to Acetone or Formaldehyde.

Answer (score 2):

About 20% of alcohol is absorbed right through the stomach after drinking.  This means alcohol *could* have a rapid effect on other aspects of digestion.  Specifically, it could affect the rate of gastric emptying, which would then affect how quickly other food is digested.  I found [one paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1429859/?page=2) which I think supports a faster rate of emptying, but [another](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8251278/) that says the rate of emptying is reduced.  [This one](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/24389403/) says it is the *sex* of the volunteers that determines this.  [They actually went on](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26700595/) to look at the menstrual cycle.  Did I say this was one of the weirder batches of PubMed results I've seen lately?  You can find many more studies of alcohol and gastric emptying on PubMed, examining disease conditions and animal models.  I suspect that overall, considering the small sample sizes and heterogeneous results, it would be easiest to classify this use of alcohol among the myriad natural supplements for which there is "insufficient evidence of efficacy".